# Get client's max int server-side

Tags: javascript, php

I have been making input fields of type `number` on the client side. I've been giving them a `max` attribute of the maximum integer value in the client's browser, using:

```js
Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER.toString()
```

Now, I'm outputting an input field on the server-side. I still want the maximum value of the field to be the client's maximum integer.

### How do I get the client's max int size from the server, without passing it?

Comment: You would need to send it to the server using AJAX and then maybe store it in a session var.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Comment: I know I could pass it, but I just wanted to know if there was a way to get it server-side easily.

Comment: I thought there may have been a server-side constant for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) is a static, constant variable. It is always 2<sup>53</sup> - 1 = **9007199254740991**.

Not sure why you would want to fetch that dynamically ever.

Comment: Okay, I forgot that. Thanks. I'll just use the number literal then.